# How can I create a node in Memgraph using Cypher that has more than one label?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that I can create a node with a label using the code:

```
CREATE (n:Person)
RETURN n;
```

But how can I add multiple labels at the time of creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to add multiple labels to a node when creating it do the following:

```
CREATE (n:Person:Department)
RETURN n;
```